# How to set string to find sheet

Tags: excel, vba

If the sheet name is "Central  " (with a space at the end of the word), zone = "Central" returns an error and the sheet cannot be activated.

How do i correct this?

```
dim wb1, wb2, wb3 as workbook
    set wb1 = activeworkbook 'the macro file
dim ws1, ws2 as worksheet
set ws1 = Sheets("Central Zone")
set ws2 = Sheets("Eastern Zone")

For x = 1 To 2
    If x = 1 Then
        Set ws = ws1
        zone = "Central"
    End If
    If x = 2 Then
        Set ws = ws2
        zone = "East"
    End If


    wb2.Sheets(zone).Activate 'wb2 is source file 1. I have wb3, wb4, etc
        Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Select
        Selection.Copy
    wb1.Activate
    ws.Activate
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Next x
```

Comment: Have you defined zone as a string with `Dim zone as String`

Comment: Yes i have. But the problem is when the actual sheet name isnt "Central" but "Central  " instead.

Comment: @AizatKassim instead of us guessing how you defined `ws` , where and what is `ws1` , please post the rest of your code here.

Comment: Right so `zone = "Central "`. Just add that space if thats the name of the sheet.

Comment: Do you have cross-sheets references? If not, why not to rename all sheets and remove the suffix space character?

Comment: @TimWilkinson The macro compiles all data from "Central" sheet in several workbooks into one sheet. Some of the central sheet might be named correctly and some of them might have a space.

Comment: In that case, you can set an exception handler such that you attempt `"Central"` and it fails, it would attempt `"Central "`.

Comment: you can use `Like` operator, with the combination of the wildcard. for instance, `If ws.Name Like "Central*" Then`

Comment: @FDavidov thanks for your reply.  Is there a way I can put an * so that the string is not limited to just "Central" and "Central  "?

Comment: I don't think so. When you reference a sheet by name, you need to provide the exact name. I'm not 100% sure about this answer (say 99%) so you may try it. My guess is that it would not work.

Comment: @AizatKassim read my commnet above yours ?

Comment: @ShaiRado thank you. How do i fit in Like operator in my current statement?

Comment: @AizatKassim if you post the rest of your code, I would know, maybe also optimize it

Comment: @AizatKassim are "Central Zone" and "Eastern Zone" sheets in the workbook where this code lies ?

Comment: @ShaiRado They are in wb1 which is the macro wb. So what is going to happen is it goes to wb2 and copy data from "Central" sheet and paste in wb1.Sheets("Central Zone") and same thing goes to wb3, wb4 and the rest

Comment: @AizatKassim and just to confirm, `wb2` is another workbook ? and this workbook is already open when you are running this code ?

Comment: @ShaiRado yes wb2 is another workbook. It is already open using a file dialog

Comment: @AizatKassim ok, and last thing : what `Range` are you trying to copy  from `Sheets("Central")` or `Sheets("East")` ? is it from cell A1 until last row in column A with data ?

Comment: @ShaiRado All cells with data. I use selection.end and then entirerow.select in my code

Comment: @AizatKassim ok, but is it 1 column ? or multiple columns ?

Comment: @ShaiRado Multiple columns.

Comment: @AizatKassim try my code below and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's allways recommended to stay away from `Activate`, `Selection`, `Select` and all other "relatives". Instead use referenced objects, like `Sheets`, and `Ranges.

The code below is a little "quick and dirty" but it should give you the result you want

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyCentralSheets()

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wb3 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, Sht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long, PasteRow As Long, x As Long

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook  ' this macro file
'Set wb2 = Workbooks("temp.xlsx")  'for my debug tests only

Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Central Zone")
Set ws2 = wb1.Sheets("Eastern Zone")

For x = 1 To 2
    If x = 1 Then
        For Each Sht In wb2.Worksheets
            If Sht.Name Like "Central*" Then
                Set ws = Sht
            End If
        Next Sht
    Else
        If x = 2 Then
            For Each Sht In wb2.Worksheets
                If Sht.Name = "East" Then
                    Set ws = Sht
                End If
            Next Sht
        End If
    End If

    With ws
        LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
        LastColumn = .UsedRange.Columns(.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Copy                
    End With

    If x = 1 Then
        With ws1
            PasteRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            .Range("A" & PasteRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlValues
        End With
    Else
        If x = 2 Then
            With ws2
                PasteRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                .Range("A" & PasteRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlValues
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this and I'll let you know the result.

Comment: I had to make some changes to make it work with the rest of my code. It worked very well. Thank you so much for the codes!

Comment: @AizatKassim please mark my answer as "ANSWER" (put a little **V** next to it)